# Jdbc Odbc Driver error

Tags: jdbc, odbc, driver

I have a small problem with `jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`.

It gives me the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support this function
```

The code:

```
saverec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        saverecclick = 1;
        if (saverecclick == 1) {
            try {
                field2.setEnabled(false);
                field3.setEnabled(false);
                field4.setEnabled(false);
                field5.setEnabled(false);
                field6.setEnabled(false);
                table.setEnabled(true);
                MainFrame();

                String myDriver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
                String myUrl = "jdbc:odbc:DLFishHunter";
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DLFishHunter");
                stmt = con.createStatement();

                String query = " insert into Data (User, Datum, Location, Kind, Size , Bait)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                java.sql.Date startDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                String suser = field0.getSelectedItem().toString();
                preparedStmt.setString(1, suser);
                preparedStmt.setDate(2, startDate);
                preparedStmt.setString(3, field3.getText());
                kinddb = field4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                preparedStmt.setString(4, kinddb);
                preparedStmt.setString(5, field5.getText());
                preparedStmt.setString(6, field6.getText());
                frame.dispose();
                preparedStmt.execute();

                try {
                    Class.forName(myDriver);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is somewhere in the code above.

Comment: Include the stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty much impossible to tell what is wrong from that code snippit.  A few things you might want to try

1) Usually the connection string includes the username and password.  Again, knowing the specific DB you are using will help.  See [this link](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwidmic70/en/managing_jobs/running_jobs/dse_using_jdbc_urls.htm) for example ODBC connection strings.

2) From `getConnection(myUrl, "root", "")`,  I'm guessing you've setup a user root with no password.  Since you're using ODBC I'm assuming you're using Sql Server, which comes setup to use a windows user as login, or a user called 'sa' - can you login via command-line/GUI with these credentials?

Comment: everything works only this save button doesnt, since i started use MS access database , before i have uses mysql xampp database and with that one it worked well , i have changed drivers and everything but it writes this error